# A list or index of .NET classes with their methods and properties in the same (huge) document?

Tags: .net, class, documentation, methods, indexing

Do you know of a list or index of .NET Framework classes with their methods and properties in the same (huge) document/web page/etc.?

I'd like to easily be able to see, for example, naming conventions: e.g. if there are many methods that start with *Create* or *Init*, etc.

Also for functionality, it would be easy to see what classes/methods are implemented that work with, let's say *AES*, or *Guid*, etc.

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to implement using reflection. First enumerate all classes in an assembly, and then all members in these classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the MSDN [Guidelines for Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx).

Beyond that, just browse MSDN to get a feel for naming conventions. You'll pick it up very quickly.